# Authenticating EC2 on EB for AWS Elastic Search HTTP requests

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam, aws-elasticsearch

I'm trying to make HTTP requests from an EC2 instance running Node.js inside elastic beanstalk to AWS Elastic Search (for insertions/index deletions/queries etc.). My issue is with the way AWS handles authentication.

There is no SDK for querying/updating etc. the documents inside elastic search indices. (There is one for managing the domain). Their recommended way to sign the requests is given [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html). In short, they use the AWS.Signers.V4 class to add the credentials to the HTTP headers, and they require the access key, secret key and session token.

The EC2 instance I'm working with does not store credentials in the environment (decision not in my hands) or in the file, which is how I was getting the credentials on my machine. It already has the correct role to access the elastic search node, **I need the best way to extract the three credentials (access key, secret key and session token)** since they are passed as an argument to the addAuthorization method. I tried logging the [CredentialProviderChain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CredentialProviderChain.html) but none of the providers had any stored credentials. Logging this locally shows both the environment variable and shared credentials file with the correct credentials as expected. I was told I should not use the assume role API (which does return the credentials), and it didn't make sense to me either since I was assuming a role the EC2 already had lol

I came across [this method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#instance-metadata-security-credentials) for retrieving instance metadata, including the security credentials. Is this my best option? Or is there an alternative I haven't considered? I'm not too thrilled about this since I'd have to add some logic to check if the process is running in the EC2 instance (so I can test locally when it's not) so it's not as clean a solution as I was expecting and I want to make sure I've explored all possibilities.

P.S. How do AWS SDKs handle authentication? I think I'd have the best chance of getting my changes approved if I use the same approach AWS uses, since elastic search is the only service we have to manually sign requests for. All the others get handled by the SDK.

Comment: This might be because I don't understand auth well, but wouldn't that be an issue when our credentials change often? Wouldn't we have to update those every time our credentials expired?

Comment: Ah alright thanks so much for the tips! I'll revert with an update at some point hopefully haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was shockingly simple and is actually documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/global-config-object.html). The AWS.config object has a getCredentials method that loads the default credentials into AWS.config.credentials and can be accessed from there, inside EC2 as well.

My guess was that it's using the EC2 instance metadata since that is indeed supposed to contain credentials but I'm not sure why when I tried logging the EC2 instance metadata provider in the CredentialProviderChain I got an empty object, whereas logging the same on my machine showed both the SharedIniFileCredentials and the Environment Credentials as containing the creds.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and a very good practice is to use SSM. System Manager has a Parameter Store and it lets you save encrypted credentials. Then all you need to do is assign an IAM Role to the EC2 with a Policy to access SSM or just edit the existing Role and give Full-SSM access to get it going then lock it down to Least Privilege.

> but wouldn't that be an issue when our credentials change often? Wouldn't we have to update those every time our credentials expired?

IAM users have rotating passwords, you need a service account password.

By default the EC2 has access to somethings because when you spin one up you have to assign the EC2 with an IAM role. Also, most EC2 AMI's come with the AWS CLI & SDK installed, so you can straight away fetch SSM Parameter store values. Here is some Python to demo:

```
ssm = boto3.client('ssm', region_name='ap-southeast-2', config=Config(proxies={'http': 'proxy:123', 'https': 'proxy:123'}))
key = "thePasswordKeyToGetTheValue"
response = ssm.get_parameter(Name=key, WithDecryption=True)
        value = response['Parameter']['Value']
```

Comment: Thanks so much yet again! I ended up finding a solution (posted as an answer) but this was super helpful in improving my understanding and is hence extremely appreciated :D